# Cross Compile OpenSceneGraph for arm processor running embedded linux?

Tags: cmake, openscenegraph

I am trying to build OpenSceneGraph(Version 3.6.5) for arm processor running embedded linux.

cmake throws different errors, can someone help ? What needs to be added in CMakeLists.txt for these errors specifically ?

**1. /mnt/sdk8_2/OpenSceneGraph/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:2:17: fatal error: cstdlib: No such file or directory
2 |        #include 
but it is there at /opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/usr/include/c++/9.2.1/cstdlib**

**2. atomic.h: No such file or directory
but following files are there**
/opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/usr/include/tbb/atomic.h
/opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/lib/modules/5.10.41-g4c2eade9f7/build/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h
/opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/lib/modules/5.10.41-g4c2eade9f7/build/include/linux/atomic.h

**3. /mnt/sdk8_2/OpenSceneGraph/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:2:17: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
But it's there at**

/opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/usr/include/boost/predef/os/windows.h
/opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/lib/modules/5.10.41-g4c2eade9f7/build/include/asm-generic/atomic.h
/opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/lib/modules/5.10.41-g4c2eade9f7/build/include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h
/opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/lib/modules/5.10.100-g7a7a3af903/build/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h
/opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/lib/modules/5.10.100-g7a7a3af903/build/include/linux/atomic.h
/opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/lib/modules/5.10.100-g7a7a3af903/build/include/asm-generic/atomic.h
/opt/arago/sysroots/aarch64-linux/lib/modules/5.10.100-g7a7a3af903/build/include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h

Comment: It's been a while since I've cross-compiled OSG on an ARM embedded box, but I didn't run into anything like these. Are you still experiencing the problem and if so, do you have any further information to add?

Comment: yes still facing the issue, i am using a docker with cross compile toolchains installed in the docker

Comment: I don't have a ready to use answer. The problem probably lies somewhere in your toolchain config. I would suggest posting this on the OSG-users mailing-list, where it's a little more practical to do q&a and interactive troubleshooting.

https://groups.google.com/g/osg-users/about